# Setting up multiple vnc connections with OS X and a Verizon router

Tags: port-forwarding

I have 2 machines set up with static ips at `192.161.1.102` and `192.168.1.103`. I can easily set up a single VNC port foreword via Verizon's infuriating interface by doing a generic VNC port forward. But when I try to set specific ports so that I can access both machines via different ports, it doesn't work. I have a feeling it has to do with the destination ports. Here is a screenshot of what I'm trying to do:

[image: port forwarding screenshot 1]

That's not working, even though I feel like it should. If I'm correct, I would then make a port forward for `192.168.1.103:5900` with the source and destination ports set to `5910`.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The trick is to leave the source ports set to `any`, and only specify the destination port.